# Final cut pro cropping at an angle

Tags: final-cut-pro-x

Is there any way in final cut pro to crop a video in a different angle to the original video?

In my case I have recorded some footage of something within a frame, some dice rolling in a box, but the angle of the box is slightly off to the camera, and I'm trying to work out if I can rotate the original footage while cropping in the previous dimension, to re-square the box, if that makes sense..?  rotating the video seems to rotate the crop are as well :/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the `Draw Mask` effect. You can essentially crop with curves, or polygon shapes

Comment: this is exactly what I needed, thankyou!